# Python: Detect if a number is divisible by any number in a list

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to filter `steps` such that it only contains numbers from 1 to `step_size` that aren't divisible by factors of `step_size`. However, the only way I can get it to work is using a flag like this, which seems to be suboptimal.

(This is part of a larger prime factorizer, which works quite well with this `prime_count`, even if it is somewhat arbitrary.)

```py
number = 651687138465 # Some integer > 1
preset_primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
# Actual code of the question starts here
prime_count = min(max(3, 1 + len(str(number)) // 3), 7)  # Arbitrary, but it works well
step_size = math.prod(preset_primes[:prime_count])
steps = [1]  # 1 is always a step, 2-4 never are
for i in range(5, step_size):
    flag_append = True
    for prime in preset_primes[:prime_count]:
        if not i % prime:
            flag_append = False
    if flag_append:
        steps.append(i)
```

Comment: Python has built-in functions `any` and `all` which evaluate iterables of logical values. You can use generator expressions with them, like `any(i % prime == 0 for prime in preset_primes)` or `all(i % prime != 0 for prime in preset_primes)`.

Comment: (@aghast: discussed in [J_H's older answer](/a/287895/93149).)

Comment: This has been done many times before, including [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146420/52915).

Answer (score 2):

## natural log

I'm unhappy with this expression:

```
prime_count = ... len(str(number)) // 3
```

Since the length computes `log10()`,
and `3` is roughly `2.718`,
it seems it would be more honest
to write `ln()`, or `math.log(number)`.

As written it is a little too magical.
If we have benchmark results showing
how FP is "too slow" in this context,
we should at least have a `# comment`
describing those timings or linking to an url.

It's also unclear why we compute `min( ... , 7)`.
The magic number should be expressed as `len(preset_primes)`.
But there's no need for it anyway, since
a "long" slice, e.g. `[:9]`, will simply consume
the seven available factors with no complaint.

---

## early exit

When we clear `flag_append = False`,
we should take the opportunity to `break`
out of the loop.

Or you might choose to rephrase that loop in terms of the
[any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)
function. (Close relative of
[all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).)

---

## numba

In the interest of speed you might want to put this code
in a type annotated helper function.
Then you could use
[numba's](https://pypi.org/project/numba)
`@njit` decorator to run it compiled
instead of running it as interpreted bytecode.

Comment: Regarding the first point - math.log(number)/math.log(1000) is identical to log10(x)/3.
But it's not quite the same as what is currently done (only for number=10**n), I will check what the performance impact is.

Comment: Oh, I read that and my first thought was it might relate to density of primes, the familiar `N / ln(N)` expression. So I didn't want the "natural log" aspect obscured. If there's something else going on there, it would be worthwhile to describe it in a `# comment`, perhaps with URL citation of some relevant math paper.

Comment: It somewhat relates, yes. In this case the following code will check these steps, shifted by a loop using `step_size` and as such for smaller numbers, creating lots of steps simply isn't worth it, while larger numbers greatly benefit. The `len(str(number)) // 3` has been a better choice than other functions I've tested and as such it's there.
Actually, `int((1 + math.log(number))/(3*math.log(10)))` (the 1+ here is required to be equal to len), which I would have assumed to be identical, returns slightly too small values for numbers close to 10**n, is that just `math.log()` being inaccurate?

Comment: Along with `break`, mention/demonstrate `for …: ‹body› else: ‹after regular termination›`.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not divisible by a factor of `step_size` iff `gcd(i, step_size) == 1`. Otherwise, that gcd is the corresponding factor or a product of multiple factors such that they divide `i`.

So you can write:

```
steps = [1]
for i in range(5, step_size):
    if math.gcd(i, step_size) == 1:
        steps.append(i)
```

You could, if you wanted, write that as a list comprehension:

```
steps = [i for i in range(1, step_size) if math.gcd(i, step_size) == 1]
```

With that caveat that I had to make the range start at 1, so 2..4 are only excluded because the product of small primes that we used includes 2 and 3.

Comment: (Would have upvoted if the question was tagged [tag:algorithm] - any insights on *performance*?)